# Why angleAtVertex() returns different value than angle_at_vertex in Field Calculator using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, geometry, vertices, angles

When using

```
angle_at_vertex($geometry,0)
324.022
```

in the Field Calculator of QGIS the values seem correct from a visual check. However when using

```
feature.geometry().angleAtVertex(0)
5.616644978134382
```

in PyQGIS it returns a different value that doesn't appear to be right.

So far I made sure that the layer's CRS and the project's CRS are the same but I am still getting the same different values. What am I missing out on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`angle_at_vertex()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#angle-at-vertex) returns the angle in *degrees*:

```
anlge_at_vertex($geometry, 0) -> 38.618825502347555 degree
```

[`angleAtVertex()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#ae4bccd7538d8653844e372f102cbbb7a) returns the angle in *radians*:

```
feature.geometry().angleAtVertex(0) -> 0.674025658269118 radian
```

For example

```
38.618825502347555 * pi / 180 = 0.674025658269118
```